# Spark two RDD join issue

Tags: python, join, apache-spark

I have two RDDs.

```
moviesRDD =[(1,'monster'),(2,'minions 3D'),...] #(movieID,title)
ratingsRDD =[(1,(3,4)),(2,(4,5)),.....]  #(movieID,(numbersofrating,avg_rating))
```

The ideal results is:

```
newRDD =[(3,'monster',4),(4,'minions 3D',5),....] #(numbersofrating,title,avg_rating)
```

I am not sure how to get newRDDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
(moviesRDD
    .join(ratingsRDD) # Join by key
    .values() # Extract values
    .map(lambda x: (x[1][0], x[0], x[1][1]))) # Reshape
```

Comment: what's the result looks like after process moviesRDD.join(ratingsRDD)

Comment: It is `(key, (v1, v2))`. For example `(1, ('monster', (3, 4)))`